# How do I get the max date for records with 2 conditions?

Tags: sql

I want to query for each `ID` the record with the **maximum date** of `date_pcp` that meets the following conditions:

1. `draft_final = F` and
2. `dsrIntExt` is not not null.

But my statement pulls the max date of the records FIRST then removes the nulls and drafts. This results in missing data because a client that had an assessment on 8/30/19 but drsIntExt is null and an assessment on 5/1/19 but data in the drsIntExt field (both in final draft) would not be included in my final data and I need that 5/1/19 record.

#### Data

```
ID  draft_final drsIntExt   date_pcp
A       F                    8/30/2019
A       F            E       5/1/2019
B       F            I       5/20/2019
C       D            E       8/31/2019
C       F            I       5/6/2019
C       F            E       12/2/2018
```

#### Expected Result

```
ID  draft_final drsIntExt   date_pcp
A   F           E           5/1/2019
B   F           I           5/20/2019
C   F           I           5/6/2019
```

#### Actual Result

```
ID  draft_final drsIntExt   date_pcp
B   F           I           5/20/2019
```

#### Current Code

```
SELECT
    l.ID,
    l.draft_final,
    l.drsIntExt,
    l.date_pcp,
    l.dsrInternalPCP_Value,
    l.dsrInternalSite_Value
FROM
    CWS.bhmp_pcp_form l
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID,
        max(date_pcp) AS MaxDatePCP
    FROM
        CWS.bhmp_pcp_form
    GROUP BY
        ID) lb ON
    l.ID = lb.ID
    AND l.date_pcp = lb.MaxDatePCP
   WHERE
        l.drsIntExt IS NOT NULL
        AND l.draft_final = 'F'
```

Comment: can you show us the results of the inner query, inside the join?

Comment: Inner Join results in max date in date_pcp for all IDs regardless of what's in dsrIntExt or draft_final data.

Comment: Ok, but I want to see the results of the inner query that is inside of that join.  W/o being able to replicate this on my own, it's hard to know what I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select t1.ID, t1.draft_final, t1.dsrIntExt, t1.date_pcp
from table1 t1
where t1.date_pcp =
(
select max(t2.date_pcp)
from table1 t2
where t2.ID = t1.ID
and t2.draft_final = 'F'
and t2.dsrIntExt is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the OVER clause might give you what you want.

```
SELECT ID,
    draft_final,
    drsIntExt,
    date_pcp
FROM
(SELECT
    l.ID,
    l.draft_final,
    l.drsIntExt,
    l.date_pcp,
    row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by date_pcp DESC
                               ) as seqnum
FROM
    bhmp_pcp_form l
WHERE
        l.drsIntExt IS NOT NULL
        AND l.draft_final = 'F') t
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Comment: To reiterate, I'm new to SQL:  When I put this in, the "row_number" is not found.  Should I change this to the equivalent field in my data?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This query is for sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

Can try the below query

```
      Select ID,  draft_final, max( drsIntExt) 
      ,max(date_pcp) from table where 
       drsIntExt IS NOT NULL and 
        draft_final='F' 
         group by
       ID,  draft_final 
        Having 1=max( case when 
        date_pcp=max(date_pcp) then 1
        else 0)
```